# Android Tablet: Automatically install/update app when connected to wifi

Tags: android, wifi, tablet

We have a large shipment of generic android tablets about to ship, and we only have enough time to install a small app at the factory before they ship.  We want this app to automatically check for the latest version of our app ('call home', if you will), and install our new app or update an existing one automatically when it's powered up and connected to wifi.

Is this possible, and is there an app out there already that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best that you can do is download the new apk from a server and prompt the user to install it.

The stock build of Android OS does not allow for installing 3rd party applications without user interaction.